# Laravel 5.8 Consulta a base de datos concreta

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Tengo un sistema con n bases de datos. Tengo que trabajar por defecto con una base de datos que se selecciona por una variable de sesión pero en una función tengo que consultar una base de datos concreta. Esto lo he solucionado definiendo en la clase Model, en el método **public function __construct(array $attributes = [])** un atributo **$this->connection=session('db');** De esta manera todas las clases consultaran la base de datos de la sesión.
El problema es que cuando he de hacer una consulta a la base de datos mysql he de poner **$cliente = DB::connection('mysql')->select('select * from clientes');**.
Alguien me podría decir cómo puedo especificar a qué base de datos va dirigida la consulta en una línea tal que así?: **$cliente = Cliente::findOrFail($bd);** El problema es que aquí me mira en la base de datos de sesión.
He probado a definir, en la clase Cliente, el atributo **protected $connection='mysql';** Pero parece que tiene prevalencia el definido en la clase Model.

Comment: Revisa este link: https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections aparece un ejemplo de conexion con varias bases de datos

Comment: Esta solución está bien para cuando quiero usar una conexión concreta para una clase en concreto pero la cuestión seria cambiar la base de datos que está utilizando para todas las consultas

Comment: Ok @AlexanderRodrigez veo que realmente tu comentario responde a mi pregunta. Gracias. Ahora lo que tengo es otra cuestión que plantearé en otro post.